# Text appears while over on an icon in Webflow

Tags: css, text, hover, icons

I made some research before writing here, but I couldn't find nothing that satisfied my answer to this specific case.

I have an icon, and when user hover onto it I want the icon become smaller and text (caption for the icon) should appear -at icons bottom.

As now, I have an interaction for the icon, that makes it become smaller.
It's first time for me working with WebFlow, and I see that using overlapping blocks they work as layers in the sense that the one on top is the only one who react to hovering.

I found in other questions that there was the need of setting correctly absolute/relative for blocks, but is not working for me since I have also the icon, inside the same block.

If I move the icon out of the block, I have the problem I shared before about overlapping "layers".

I need that icon decrease in size and text appear at the same time.

Is this achievable?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve